# Load an image with either JPG extension or PNG one

Tags: flutter, dart

In my Flutter app, I return asset (product image) name by:

```dart
class Product {
    // ...
    final int id;
    // ...
    String get assetName => '$id-0.jpg';
}
```

And later, I use the asset name like:

```dart
// ...
image: AssetImage(product.assetName),
// ...
```

Now, the problem is some of the images are `*.jpg` and some are `*.png` like:

[image: Screenshot]

Is there a way to tell the Flutter image loader to try to load `'$id-0.jpg'` and if the file doesn't exist, then try to load `'$id-0.png'`? Perhaps I can do that with regular expressions, but I cannot figure out how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can determine if an asset exists with `rootBundle.load` and a `try-catch` block. `rootBundle.load` will throw an exception if the asset is not found.

```dart
ByteData image;
try{
  image = await rootBundle.load(assetNameHere.jpg);
}
catch(e) {
  image = await rootBundle.load(assetNameHere.png);
}
```

I don't know the exception that this will throw on the asset not existing, so I can't tell you which error to catch `on`, but you can figure that out and modify your code to only do the png code on that exception type instead of everything.

With this method, since you're already forced to load the image into memory, you can store the `ByteData` and use `MemoryImage` instead of `AssetImage`.

Comment: Also, [such conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56573060/3405291) is needed.

Comment: Moreover, due to using `await` keyword, I had to note [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53801912/3405291) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53364252/3405291) ...